# Identifying the un used cluster keys and unused data in Snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi my intention is to reduce the bill that we pay for using the snowflakes cloud service.

Part#1
 I like to know is there a way to find the unused data(that was not be reference by select statements and other DML) so that i can go ahead and truncate the data.I know we need to pay for truncating the data but thats  one time which in turn helps in future storage spendings .

Part#2
How to list down the cluster keys defined in a database ?and how to drop unwanted ones ,so that we can avoid cost during the updates to data in the table that has unwanted cluster key.

Answer (score 0):

The only current way to handle #1 is to use query_history to see what tables are being used.  This is obviously difficult since parsing query_text is difficult and if views are used, you will not see which tables are used underneath.  Snowflake recently released EXPLAIN, which I believe is the first step towards providing more lineage to tables and what is being queried over time.  But, today it isn't easy.

The 2nd part is a bit easier, though.  A `SHOW TABLES` command provides you with the full list of tables for a schema and the cluster keys are included in that query.  To drop them, you simply run an `ALTER TABLE` statement and remove the cluster keys.

Comment: How do we decide whether the clustering  key is needed or not on a table ?